# Placeholder is showing like dots insted of placeholder text(Default text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Placeholder is not working in below IE10 browsers, meanwhile i wrote following code it is working fine.
But problem is in password field it shows dots instead of placeholder text. Please find the attached screen shot.
Here is my code, could you please  help is there any solution for fixing the password field placeholder visible.

```
//Default text in login page.
(function ($) {
    $.support.placeholder = ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'));
})(jQuery);


//fix for IE7 and IE8
$(function () {
    if (!$.support.placeholder) {
        $("[placeholder]").focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
        }).blur();

        $("[placeholder]").parents("login").submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });
        });
    }
});![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: A password field will always show dots in place of text, that is the entire point.

Comment: You are right...but I would like to show the placeholder in password field like (Enter password).

Comment: The first (easiest) solution that comes to mind would be to use a background image with the text. Or place an element over the top of the pw field until clicked? A few things are available.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below, it will help you

```
$(function () {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  if (('placeholder' in input) == false) {
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
      var i = $(this);
      if (i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
        i.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
        if (i.hasClass('password')) {
          i.removeClass('password');
          this.type = 'password';
        }
      }
    }).blur(function () {
      var i = $(this);
      if (i.val() == '' || i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
        if (this.type == 'password') {
          i.addClass('password');
          this.type = 'text';
        }
        i.addClass('placeholder').val(i.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function () {
      $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
        var i = $(this);
        if (i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
          i.val('');
      })
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will go a long way towards helping current and future readers understand your answer even better.